# Can I use shinytest with a Shiny App that produces PDFs from an Rmd template?

Tags: r, unit-testing, shiny, shinydashboard, tinytex

I'm working on a relatively complex shiny app that allows for a wide variety of user inputs.  These user inputs are then used for a series of calculations and they're presented in the form of several tables and graphs.  The final results can then be downloaded in the form of a PDF that is generated from a custom `.Rmd` template and `.tex` files.  This relies on tinytex.

Up to this point, I've been testing the app manually.  However, I'm interested in using `shinytest` to create a more robust testing pipeline.  I've followed the documentation and I've run into the following issue.

```
Running mytest.R Error in is_rmd(path) : 
  Unknown whether app is a regular Shiny app or .Rmd: C:/Users/maxwe/OneDrive/Documents/PATH_TO_TEST/tests/R
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> as.list -> as.list.environment -> is_rmd
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="C:/Users/maxwe/OneDrive/Documents/PATH_TO_TEST/R/tests/R": The system cannot find the file specified
Execution halted
```

Is `shinytest` getting confused when it detects the `.Rmd` file? My application is structured as a CRAN package (see below).

```
Package --- inst
            man
            packrat
            R ---
                  reports --- *.Rmd, *.tex
            rsconnect
            test
```

Is it possible for me to use `shinytest` to test this app? Or would I need to use a different approach?